# Flutter show value from an array

Tags: flutter

I have some fixed list of products like this

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String normalPrice;
  final String discountPrice;
  final double ratingValue;
  final String description;
  final bool isOffer;
  final List<String> images;
  final List colors;

  const Product({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.normalPrice,
    this.discountPrice,
    this.ratingValue,
    this.description,
    this.images,
    this.isOffer,
    this.colors,
  });
}



List<Product> productList = [
  Product(
      id: 1,
      title: "Nike Air Zoom Tempo Next",
      image: "assets/images/products/1_0.jpg",
      discountPrice: "0",
      normalPrice: "150",
      ratingValue: 4.0,
      isOffer: false,
      colors: [
        {
          'color': 'Red',
          'image': "assets/images/products/ps4_console_blue_1.png",
        },
        {
          'color': 'Orange',
          'image': "assets/images/products/ps4_console_blue_2.png",
        }

      ],
      description:
          "The Nike Air Zoom Tempo Next% mixes durability with a design that helps push you towards your personal best. The result is a shoe built like a racer, but made for your everyday training routine.",
      images: [
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_blue_1.png",
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_white_4.png",
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_white_2.png",
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_white_3.png",
      ]),
  
];
```

I am showing images, title price etc in widget all is working fine. What i need to do is i need to show the color in a colors array. can anyone please tell how can i show this in Text widget ?

I am simple showing price and color in a column.

```
Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
            child: Text(
              "\$ ${widget.product.normalPrice}",
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .headline1
                  .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
          ),
          Text(widget.product.colors[0].color)
        ],
      ),
```

Its showing normalPrice correctly but on color its showing error of `Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' has no instance getter 'color'.`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in a JS way, you can't just call `.color` because it is not a property of a class, it is a `Map` object so you have to call it with square brackets like so: `Text(widget.product.colors[0]['color'])`

But I do recommend you to make a class with those fields as then your IDE will show you autocomplete options

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate class if you would like to call `.color`

like so:

```dart
class MyColor {
  final String color;
  final String image;

  const MyColor({
    this.color,
    this.image,
  });
}

class Product {
  final int id;
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String normalPrice;
  final String discountPrice;
  final double ratingValue;
  final String description;
  final bool isOffer;
  final List<String> images;
  final List<MyColor> colors;

  const Product({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.normalPrice,
    this.discountPrice,
    this.ratingValue,
    this.description,
    this.images,
    this.isOffer,
    this.colors,
  });
}
```

then you can create your product list

```dart
List<Product> productList = [
  Product(
      id: 1,
      title: "Nike Air Zoom Tempo Next",
      image: "assets/images/products/1_0.jpg",
      discountPrice: "0",
      normalPrice: "150",
      ratingValue: 4.0,
      isOffer: false,
      colors: [
        MyColor(
          color: 'Red',
          image: 'assets/images/products/ps4_console_blue_1.png',
        ),
        MyColor(
          color: 'Orange',
          image: 'assets/images/products/ps4_console_blue_2.png',
        ),
      ],
      description:
          "The Nike Air Zoom Tempo Next% mixes durability with a design that helps push you towards your personal best. The result is a shoe built like a racer, but made for your everyday training routine.",
      images: [
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_blue_1.png",
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_white_4.png",
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_white_2.png",
        "assets/images/products/ps4_console_white_3.png",
      ]),
];
```

and your widget will now work

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key key, this.product}) : super(key: key);
  final Product product;

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
            child: Text(
              "\$ ${widget.product.normalPrice}",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
          ),
          Text(widget.product.colors[0].color)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```